# raster2pgsql stops at line 53 at RETURN

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I am importing some very large rasters (in the tif format) into Postgres SQL (9.3) using raster2pgsql on the command line. Most of the rasters imported fine, some had to be converted to the img format and then imported fine, but some more have not imported at all. They appear to work, and the normal import line comes up, and then I get the following:

```
NOTICE:  Adding nodata value constraint
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function addrasterconstraints(name,name,name,boolean,boolean,
boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean)
line 53 at RETURN
NOTICE:  Adding out-of-database constraint
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function addrasterconstraints(name,name,name,boolean,boolean,
boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean)
line 53 at RETURN
NOTICE:  Adding maximum extent constraint
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function addrasterconstraints(name,name,name,boolean,boolean,
boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean)
line 53 at RETURN
```

and the import appears to make no further progress.

I have searched the metadata and found no differences at all from the files that worked, the same command was used to import them all:

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/124031/1897

Comment: Thanks, for the record, removing -c from the command fixed the problem